# using XSLT to select multiple child nodes

Tags: xslt-1.0

I'm having a bit of trouble selecting exactly what I want in the following input XML. 
I need to essentially select by `keys/key` , where there are multiple `<key>` child nodes.

For example, here's a sample input XML file :

```
  <Outbound environment="" request="selectPortfolios">
<body matchedRecordCount="4">       
    <portfolioSummary portfolioId="36">
        <portfolio id="36">
            <currency>USD</currency>
            <keys>
                <key displayValue="DummyCounterpartyIRS" sequenceNumber="100" sequenceValue="DummyCounterpartyIRS" type="Counterparty" value="DummyCounterpartyIRS"/>
                <key displayValue="Internal VaR IRS LCH" sequenceNumber="2000" sequenceValue="80" type="ExpType" value="InternalVaR_IRS_LCH"/>
            </keys>
            <status>Unapproved</status>
        </portfolio>
        <exposureProfile>
            <node date="2014-05-06">
                <tag>HSVaR 5D 100 ES</tag>
                <exposure>492692</exposure>
            </node>
        </exposureProfile>
    </portfolioSummary>
    <portfolioSummary portfolioId="37">     
        <portfolio id="37">
            <currency>USD</currency>
            <keys>
                <key displayValue="DummyCounterpartyIRS" sequenceNumber="100" sequenceValue="DummyCounterpartyIRS" type="Counterparty" value="DummyCounterpartyIRS"/>
                <key displayValue="Internal VaR CDS LCH" sequenceNumber="2000" sequenceValue="81" type="ExpType" value="InternalVaR_CDS_LCH"/>
            </keys>
            <status>Unapproved</status>
        </portfolio>
        <exposureProfile>
            <node date="2014-05-09">
                <tag>Node Scenario 4</tag>
                <exposure>248057</exposure>
            </node>
            <node date="2014-05-10">
                <tag>Node Scenario 5</tag>
                <exposure>373130</exposure>
            </node>
            <node date="2014-05-11">
                <tag>EXPECTED_SHORTFALL 99.7</tag>
                <exposure>373130</exposure>
            </node>
        </exposureProfile>
    </portfolioSummary>
    <portfolioSummary portfolioId="71">
        <readOnly>false</readOnly>
        <portfolio id="71">
            <currency>USD</currency>
            <keys>
                <key displayValue="DummyCounterpartyCDS" sequenceNumber="100" sequenceValue="DummyCounterpartyCDS" type="Counterparty" value="DummyCounterpartyCDS"/>
                <key displayValue="Internal VaR IRS LCH" sequenceNumber="2000" sequenceValue="80" type="ExpType" value="InternalVaR_IRS_LCH"/>
            </keys>         
            <status>Unapproved</status>
        </portfolio>
        <exposureProfile>
            <node date="2014-05-06">
                <tag>HSVaR 5D 100 ES</tag>
                <exposure>58</exposure>
            </node>
        </exposureProfile>
    </portfolioSummary>
    <portfolioSummary portfolioId="72">
        <readOnly>false</readOnly>
        <portfolio id="72">
            <currency>USD</currency>
            <keys>
                <key displayValue="DummyCounterpartyCDS" sequenceNumber="100" sequenceValue="DummyCounterpartyCDS" type="Counterparty" value="DummyCounterpartyCDS"/>
                <key displayValue="Internal VaR CDS LCH" sequenceNumber="2000" sequenceValue="81" type="ExpType" value="InternalVaR_CDS_LCH"/>
            </keys>
            <status>Unapproved</status>
        </portfolio>
        <exposureProfile>
            <node date="2014-05-09">
                <tag>Node Scenario 4</tag>
                <exposure>9</exposure>
            </node>
            <node date="2014-05-10">
                <tag>Node Scenario 5</tag>
                <exposure>12</exposure>
            </node>
            <node date="2014-05-11">
                <tag>EXPECTED_SHORTFALL 99.7</tag>
                <exposure>12</exposure>
            </node>
        </exposureProfile>
    </portfolioSummary>
</body>
</Outbound>
```

The specific `<portfolioSummary>` nodes I want are based on the `<key>` attributes:

1) First XSLT template: 
   1a) where attribute type="Counterparty" and value="DummyCounterpartyIRS" AND
   1b) where attribute type="ExpType" AND value="InternalVaR_IRS_LCH"

2) Second XSLT template: 
    2a) where attribute type="Counterparty" value="DummyCounterpartyCDS" AND 
    2b) where attributes type="ExpType" AND value="InternalVaR_CDS_LCH"

It should end up pulling TWO `<portfolioSummary>` nodes for both portfolioId="36" and portfolioId="72"

Here's what I have, but it's not selecting properly:

```
   <?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<xsl:stylesheet xmlns:xsl="http://www.w3.org/1999/XSL/Transform"
xmlns:xs="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema"
xmlns:xd="http://www.oxygenxml.com/ns/doc/xsl"
exclude-result-prefixes="xs xd"
version="1.0">
<!-- Variable declaration -->
<xsl:variable name="hsVar1D" select="'1D (99%)'"></xsl:variable>
<xsl:variable name="hsVar5D" select="'HSVaR 5D 100 ES'"></xsl:variable>

<!-- Pull portfolioSummary nodes for HSVaR -->
<xsl:template match="/*">
    <collection>
        <xsl:apply-templates select="/Outbound/body/portfolioSummary[descendant::portfolio/keys/key[@type='Counterparty' and @value='DummyCounterpartyIRS']]"/>
        <xsl:apply-templates select="/Outbound/body/portfolioSummary[descendant::portfolio/keys/key[@type='Counterparty' and @value='DummyCounterpartyCDS']]"/>

    </collection>
</xsl:template>
<xsl:template match="*">
    <xsl:choose>
        <xsl:when test="descendant::portfolio/keys/key[@type='ExpType' and @value='InternalVaR_IRS_LCH']">
        <extIA>
            <AGREEMENTID><xsl:value-of select="@portfolioId"></xsl:value-of></AGREEMENTID>
            <legal_id><xsl:value-of select="portfolio/keys/key[@type='Counterparty']/@displayValue"/></legal_id>
            <PRODUCT><xsl:value-of select="portfolio/keys/key[@type='Counterparty']/@displayValue"/></PRODUCT>               
            <AMOUNT><xsl:value-of select="exposureProfile/node[tag/text()[contains(.,$hsVar5D)]]/exposure"/></AMOUNT>
            <CURRENCY><xsl:value-of select="bandStructure/currency"/></CURRENCY>
            <ValuationDate>2012-05-15</ValuationDate>
            <externalSystem>MY EXT SYSTEM</externalSystem>
        </extIA>
        </xsl:when>
        <xsl:when test="descendant::portfolio/keys/key[@type='ExpType' and @value='InternalVaR_CDS_LCH']">
            <extIA>
                <AGREEMENTID><xsl:value-of select="@portfolioId"></xsl:value-of></AGREEMENTID>
                <legal_id><xsl:value-of select="portfolio/keys/key[@type='Counterparty']/@displayValue"/></legal_id>
                <PRODUCT><xsl:value-of select="portfolio/keys/key[@type='ExpType']/@displayValue"/></PRODUCT>
                                    <AMOUNT><xsl:value-of select="exposureProfile/node[tag/text()[contains(.,$hsVar5D)]]/exposure"/></AMOUNT>
                <CURRENCY><xsl:value-of select="bandStructure/currency"/></CURRENCY>
                <ValuationDate>2012-05-15</ValuationDate>
                <externalSystem>MY EXT SYSTEM</externalSystem>
            </extIA>
        </xsl:when>
        <xsl:otherwise></xsl:otherwise>
    </xsl:choose>

</xsl:template>
</xsl:stylesheet>
```

Answer (score 1):

The `<xsl:apply-templates>` in your first template are not selecting anything. You are matching `/*` and selecting an *absolute* location path which starts with an element that does not exist: `razorOutbound`.

Change it to:

```
<xsl:template match="/">
    <collection>
        <xsl:apply-templates select="Outbound/body/portfolioSummary[descendant::portfolio/keys/key[@type='Counterparty' and @value='DummyCounterpartyIRS']]"/>
        <xsl:apply-templates select="Outbound/body/portfolioSummary[descendant::portfolio/keys/key[@type='Counterparty' and @value='DummyCounterpartyCDS']]"/>
    </collection>
</xsl:template>
```

As for the selections, *four* portfolios are selected, and not two. The first expression:

```
//body/portfolioSummary[portfolio/keys/key[@type='Counterparty' and @value='DummyCounterpartyIRS']]
```

will match *two* portfolios (36 and 37), and the other will match 71 and 72. The `*` template will be called twice for each pair and will always match one or the other `xsl:when`. If you want to select only one of each, you have to add some other restriction to it.

Comment: I was scrubbing the source XML data, and inadvertently left the old values. But yes, it should read `<OutBound>` .

Comment: So if I loop through each `<key>` node every time my final template is executed (i.e. `<xsl:for-each select="portfolio/keys/key">`, couldn't I use an if statement to narrow my selection as in: 
  `<xsl:if test="(@type='ExpType') and (@value='Internal VaR IRS LCH')"> `